# Logarithmic barrier function for a multivariable constraint problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

Suppose we have the following optimization problem to solve:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textbf{(P1)}~~~~~~~~ \underset{x_1, \, x_2, \,x_3}{\text{minimize}}\, \left\{ \, f\left(x_1, \, x_2, \, x_3 \right) + \lambda \, \Big(g\left(x_1\right) + g\left(x_2\right) + g\left(x_3\right) \Big) \, \right\}
\\
s.t. \,\,\,\,\,\,\, x_1\geq 0
\\
x_1 + x_2^2 - 5 \geq 0
\\
x_3 - 25 \geq 0 \,.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where both $f$ and $g$ are convex functions.

How can I apply the logarithmic barrier function in order to transform problem **(P1)** into an unconstrained problem? BTW I am doing that as follows:

\begin{equation}
\small
\textbf{(P2)} ~~~~~~~~\underset{x_1, \, x_2, \, x_3}{\text{minimize}} \, \left\{\, f\left(x_1, \, x_2, \, x_3 \right) + \lambda \, \Big(g\left(x_1\right) + g\left(x_2\right) + g\left(x_3\right) \Big)  - \mu \, \sum_{i=1}^3 \, ln\Big( c_i(x) \Big)\, \right\}
\end{equation}
with $c_1(x) = x_1$, $~~c_2(x) = x_1 + x_2^2 - 5$, $~~$ and $~~c_3(x) = x_3 - 25$.

Is my use of the logarithmic barrier function right to transform problem **(P1)** into **(P2)**? If not, can someone provide me details about how can I do it in the right way?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: The barrier function is correct. Note that the original problem is not convex, so the tag 'convex optimization' is not appropriate.

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you again for all your help. I still have one question, do you think that the minimization has to be done recursively? For example $x_1^{k} = \underset{x_1}{argmin}\, \left\{f(x_1,\,x_2^{k-1},\,x_3^{k-1}) + \lambda\, g\left(x_1\right) - \mu \, \left(  ln\left(x_1\right) + ln\left(x_1 + x_2^{k-1} -5 \right) \right) \right\}$ and then $x_2^{k} = \underset{x_2}{argmin}\, \left\{f(x_1^{k},\,x_2,\,x_3^{k-1}) + \lambda\, g\left(x_2\right) - \mu \, \left(  ln\left(x_1^{k}\right) + ln\left(x_1^{k} + x_2 -5 \right) \right) \right\}$ and so on ... Am I right?

Comment: I recommend reading a paper about interior point methods, typically you take a quadratic approximation of the objective and a linear approximation of the constraints so the $argmin_x$ is easier, and you also update $\mu$ in between iterations

Comment: @LinAlg Yes Thank you I will do that!